# Batch files/table read ins

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a little script that will help my office automate the uploading of zips and self extractors to a ftp site.  They have to create several zips/se's and name them various different things etc.

My idea is for them to have a little table they could type in (i.e. the name they want the file to be called, the location of the upload, where they want it to extract to etc) and then my program would handle it effectively (so when they want to upload that 'row of data' they just select via a GUI and run the script).

I am new to batch files and programming in general.  Just wondering if anyone has a tip for having a batch file read in data from a table somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this help?

With data file Data.txt

```
One,Two,Three
A,B,C
```

Cmd file ReadData.cmd

```
@echo off

  for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in (data.txt) do call :EachLine %%A %%B %%C

goto :eof 

:EachLine 
  @echo First is %1 Second is %2 Third is %3
goto :eof
```

Gives output of

```
First is One Second is Two Third is Three
First is A Second is B Third is C
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do GUI , you can try [HTA programming](http://tinyurl.com/yaau28y).  you can create tables etc.